# getUserMedia in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I can't display the video stream in Google Chrome (v21)

Code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    if(navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, function(stream) {
            var video = document.getElementById('sourcevid');
            video.src = stream;
        }, function(error) {
            console.error(error.code);
        });        
    } else {
        console.log('Not supported in this browser.');
    }
}, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <video id="sourcevid" autoplay>Put your fallback message here.</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me understand where the problem is.

Comment: If one of the answers helped you, it would be nice to mark it as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by calling the play method on the video element. Even if you add the autoplay attribute, it won't work. My best guess for that is that at the moment of loading the video tag the source is empty so it can't start.

```
    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.getUserMedia;
    var success = function(stream){
      var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
      video.src = webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
      //Even if autoplay is true you need to call the play method
      video.play();
    }
    var error = function(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
    navigator.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:true}, success, error);
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work unless you have the `flag` for Chrome `Enable PeerConnection` enabled...

1) Go to the web address `about:flags` in Chrome
2) Find `Enable PeerConnection`
3) Enable it
4) Restart Chrome
5) ???
6) Profit...?

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue but it is just resolved by adding source with blank initially.

```
<video id="sourcevid" src="" autoplay>Put your fallback message here.</video>
```